# Find index all indexes in another list where the values is the same as this from the first list

Tags: java, groovy

How could I get index of an element from a List in another List? I mean I have list with values. And the second list contains one of the values from the first array. ['A', 'B', 'C'] and the second is ['B', 'A', 'C'] how to loop over it and search indexes of those elements? And loop through until all indexes will be found.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add the code to the question and explain what errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just comparing strings, and there is only one occurring value you want the index of in the second list, you can use the indexOf method in conjunction with a loop as so:

```
    Map<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(int x = 0; x < listOne.size(); x++){
        indexMap.put(listOne.get(x), listTwo.indexOf(listOne.get(x).toString()));
    }
```

And to get the index, just simply call the get method using the key of the value that you want:

```
indexMap.get("A");
```